# When using MySQL's GROUP BY, what guarantees are there about what data is put into the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we want to find the max or min age for a person with a specific name.

We can do:

```
select name, min(age) from users group by name;
select name, max(age) from users group by name;
```

`min` and `max` are clearly documented with other aggregate functions.

Another way to (seemingly) accomplish the above is as follows:

```
select name, age from (select name, age from users order by age asc) sorted group by name;
select name, age from (select name, age from users order by age desc) sorted group by name;
```

Although this works, it relies on the guarantee that when building a result set, MySQL will take the content from the first record found, in the case that there are multiple records for the group by field.

I cannot find documentation that clearly states such a guarantee to be true. Is it?

Comment: Just wondering .... how one user have different ages?

Comment: it doesn't have to be one user, it could be the name of multiple users (not the username or the unique name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
>   SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
>   are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL
>   to accept the preceding query. ***In this case, the server is free to
>   choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs
>   after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which
>   value within each group the server chooses.*** Disabling
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some
>   property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not
>   named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

So, adding an `order by` does not provide any guarantee that the first value from the group will be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Your first version is correct.  The second version is patently incorrect and documented as such.  Here is the example in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> ```
>   SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
>   FROM orders AS o, customers AS c  [sic . . . why doesn't the documentation use JOIN???]
>   WHERE o.custid = c.custid
>   GROUP BY o.custid;
> ```
>
> . . .
>
> If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, **the values chosen are indeterminate**, which is probably not what you want.